# Temporary store object attributes

Tags: jquery, image, src, temporary

This is what i am trying,

- run script turning every picture to a dummy one.
- onclick, an image switching back to the original.

That is my actuall code:

```
 actobjSrc = $(actobj).attr('src');
 $(actobj).attr('oldsrc', actobjSrc);
 $(actobj).attr('src', 'temp.png');

 $('img').click(function(){
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('oldsrc'));
 });
```

Resulting in:
**"XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (name, value)..."**

Comment: If that's precisely your code, there's a wrong dot '.' in between "attr" and ('oldsrc') in your click function...

Comment: Check $(this).attr.('oldsrc') and correct it to $(this).attr('oldsrc'). Also try with $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method

```
$("img").data("old", $(this).attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).attr('src', function(){return $(this).attr('oldsrc');});
```

Comment: Not solving the problem..
XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (a, b) {return f.access(this, a, b, !0, f.attr);})

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('oldsrc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You put an extra dot here:

```
 $(this).attr.('oldsrc')
```

should be

```
 $(this).attr('oldsrc')
```

Answer (score 0):

[As the fiddle suggests](http://jsfiddle.net/ws6qz/), your code sample actually works as it is

your trouble probably lies in

- defining the `actobj` beforeheads
- or referencing the .png file (is 'temp.png' your actual reference? it should be a valid ref to an image file e.g. accessible from the browser)

I cannot infer any more from your code, so please give some more info

Comment: 1. it is defined
2. it is a regular path and also a regular image

Comment: Did you correct the error in `$(this).attr.('oldsrc')` to `$(this).attr('oldsrc')` in your working code as you did in your question example? 
And it still isn't working?